# Binding two properties of object in DataTamplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have GridControl (Devexpress) with ItemsSource="{Binding Flow}". I implemented grouping by TagRange column. I want to change GroupValue.

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Tag Range" Binding="{Binding Path=TagRange}" GroupIndex="0" >
    <dxg:GridColumn.GroupValueTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.GroupValueTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

The text of TextBlock equals TagRange property. How can I bind TextBlock Text property as `Name + " " +  TagRange`.

Flow class:

```
public class Flow
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string TagRange { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this purely in XAML, use Run elements:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/> <Run Text="{Binding TagRange}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Alternatively, you could create a composite property in your model / viewmodel  and bind to that:

```
public class Flow
{
    public string Text => $"{Name} {TagRange}";
    // ...
}
```